# How can I know the actual size of Image File in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a rich text editor using contenteditable div using javascript. which allows users to drop and copy-paste images.
I have kept a file limitation of 5mb.
Scenario1:
If a user drops an image into the editor using file properties I am displaying an error message.its working fine.
Scenario2:
If a user copy(ctrl+C) an image it is getting converted into base64Image in the clipboard.
using file reader when I check the size its showing 29MB for 5Mb file.
I know the file size is increased because of base64 encrypting I have tried atob() and btoa() but still not helpful
how can I able to get the original file size ??

## code

```
function PasteImage(event){           
var items=(event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;         
var blob=items[0].getAsFile();         
console.log(blob.size)--gives 26mb which is formed by base64 encoded.      

}
```

I would like to know is there any possibility to get the actual size file.

Comment: please give code sample for helping people to help you.

Comment: i guess you in your richtext-editor you would just save like an img tag with filled src property and you do an actual upload of the pictures

Comment: yes, I will save as image tag but before creating ImageTag I want to give alert to the user regarding the restricting

Answer (score 1):

on change of input type file you can get the file size:

Like

```
 <input type="file" id="fileInput" />

    $('#fileInput').on('change', function() {

       alert(this.files[0].size);

    });
```

Comment: How is `input type="file"` related to rich text editing with drop and copy-paste?

Comment: you can  get the files from clipboard event when you drop and paste
paste
(event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
drop
event.originalEvent.target.files || event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;